# POM not working on multiple test of TestNG

Tags: selenium

Below are my classes of POM:

**Home**

```java
package com.sec.page;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class Home {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(linkText = "Frequency Calculator")
    WebElement frqcalc_page;

    @FindBy(linkText = "Radial O-ring Selector")
    WebElement radslct_page;


    public Home(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public Freq_Calc clickFreqCalcPage() {
        frqcalc_page.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver,Freq_Calc.class);
    }

    public Radial_Selector clickRadialSelectorPage() {
        radslct_page.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver,Radial_Selector.class);
    }   

}
```

**Freq_Calc**

```java
package com.sec.page;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Freq_Calc {
    private WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(linkText = "Bearing Frequencies Calculator")
    WebElement BrgFreqCalc;

    @FindBy(linkText = "Gearbox Calculator")
    WebElement GearCalc;

    @FindBy(linkText = "Overview")
    WebElement overview_page;

    public Freq_Calc(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;

    }

    public Freq_Calc_BrgFreqCalc clickBrgFreqCalc(){
        BrgFreqCalc.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Freq_Calc_BrgFreqCalc.class);
    }

}
```

**Radial_Selector**

```java
package com.sec.page;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Radial_Selector {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(name = "boreDiameter")
    WebElement boreDiameter;

    @FindBy(name = "boreTolerance")
    WebElement boreTolerance;


    @FindBy(css = "input[value='Calculate']")
    WebElement calculate;

    public Radial_Selector(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;

    }

    public Radial_Selector enterboreDiameter(String value) {
        boreDiameter.sendKeys(value);   
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Radial_Selector.class);

    }

    public Radial_Selector enterboreTolerance(String value) {
        boreTolerance.sendKeys(value);  
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Radial_Selector.class);
    }


    public Radial_Selector clickcalculate() {
        calculate.click();  
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, Radial_Selector.class);
    }

}
```

**TestBase**

```java
package com.sec.util;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import com.sec.page.Freq_Calc;
import com.sec.page.Home;
import com.sec.page.Radial_Selector;


public class TestBaseSEC {          

    protected  WebDriver driver=null;
    protected String baseUrl;
    protected Home homePage;
    protected Radial_Selector radialselector;
    protected Freq_Calc freqcalc;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        baseUrl = "http://10.177.2.60:8080/engcalc/";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Testcase:**

```java
package com.sec.scripts;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    
import com.sec.page.Home;
import com.sec.util.TestBaseSEC;


public class TestCaseSEC extends TestBaseSEC{

    @Test
    public void Test_RadialSelector_Page() throws Exception {
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home.class);
        driver.get(baseUrl);        
        radialselector = homePage.clickRadialSelectorPage();
        radialselector.enterboreDiameter("10"); 
        radialselector.enterboreTolerance("12");
        radialselector.clickcalculate();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-navigation']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();

    }
    @Test
    public void Test_Freq_Calc_BrgFreqCalc_Page() throws Exception {
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home.class);
        freqcalc = homePage.clickFreqCalcPage();
    }
}
```

My isssue is:
    Whenn I run Testcase, The first @Test works fine. but when it goes to second @Test, where "freqcalc =homePage.clickFreqCalcPage()"is used, it tells there is no locator for Frequency Calculator, but that exist.
    Also if I use "freqcalc =homePage.clickFreqCalcPage()" as last line in first @Test then it works.

```
So I want to understand why it does not work for second @Test.
```

Comment: What happens in the last line of test1(click line). does it navigate to another page? Seems like test2 requires to be on the home page and browser has navigated to another page.

Comment: Yes, Last line click navigates to homepage.

Comment: It does not navigate to other page because as mentioned when I use same     freqcalc =homePage.clickFreqCalcPage()  in first @Test, it does navigate from home page to Freq_Calc page

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of a lot of things in your code as follows :

- Loading the page elements even before accessing the url makes no sense. Hence first load the **`URL`** then **`initialize`** the **`WebElements`** on the **`Page Object`**.
- When you **`initialize`** a **`Page Object`** get back the object in return.

  ```
  driver.get(baseUrl); 
  Home homePage  = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home.class);
  ```
- Use the returned **`Page Object`** to access it's methods.

  ```
  homePage.clickRadialSelectorPage();
  ```
- Avoid chaining of **`Page Objects`** i.e. **`initialization`** of another **`Page Object`** through **`return`** statement, rather **`initialize`** the required **`Page Object`** in your **`Test class`**.

  ```
  //avoid
  return PageFactory.initElements(driver,Radial_Selector.class);

  //within Test Class
  Radial_Selector radialselector = PageFactory.initElements(driver,Radial_Selector.class);
  radialselector.enterboreDiameter("10");
  ```
- As you are having seperate **`Page Objects`** for different pages try to define the locators e.g. **`xpath`** for the associated **`WebElement`** in the respective **`Page Objects`** only.

  ```
  //avoid
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-navigation']/ul/li[1]/a/span"));
  ```
- As you are having seperate **`Page Objects`** for different pages try to define the **`Page Object Methods`** e.g. **`click()`** for the **`WebElement`**'s in the respective **`Page Factory`** only.

  ```
  //avoid
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-navigation']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
  ```

> **`First @Test`** works fine because, though you try to initialize **`Home.class`** nothing really happens. When **`driver.get(baseUrl);`** gets executed the elements gets initialized and your **`@Test`** gets passed. But that's not the case with **`Second @Test`**. Hence **Fails**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, the URL is not launched in the second test when the page got initialized because it is missed in the second test.

**Solution 1:**
Please add the line `driver.get(baseUrl)` in your second test as given below.

```
@Test
public void Test_Freq_Calc_BrgFreqCalc_Page() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home.class);
    freqcalc = homePage.clickFreqCalcPage();
}
```

**Solution 2:** Move the launch URL step to before Test method. Then remove it in first test as given below.

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    baseUrl = "http://10.177.2.60:8080/engcalc/";
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}
```

then remove it in the first test as given below.

```
@Test
public void Test_RadialSelector_Page() throws Exception {
    homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Home.class);
 // driver.get(baseUrl);        
    radialselector = homePage.clickRadialSelectorPage();
    radialselector.enterboreDiameter("10"); 
    radialselector.enterboreTolerance("12");
    radialselector.clickcalculate();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='top-navigation']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();

}
```